# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in my dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to build a dictionary, but before adding a new element, I have to check that this element is not already in the dictionary. The way it is constructed, my dictionary `s` has keys that are strings (not lists). That is why I do not know why I get this error message: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

```
men=['h1','h2','h3']
women=['f1','f2','f3']
pref={'h1':['f2','f1','f3'],'h2':['f2','f1','f3'],'h3':['f3','f2','f1']}
rank={'f1':{'h3','h1','h2'},'f2':{'h3','h2','h1'},'f3':{'h1','h2','h3'}}
for n in pref:
   pref[n].reverse()
freemen=men
l=len(men)
s={}
while freemen:
   m=freemen.pop()
   if len(pref[m])==0:
      continue
   w=pref[m]
   if w not in s:
       s[w]=m
   else:
     mprime=s[w]
     if rank[w][m]<rank[w][mprime]:
         s[w]=m
         freemen.append(mprime)
     else:
         freemen.append(m)
print(s)
```

Comment: Anyway, your problem is this: You say `w=pref[m]`, so `w` is a list. Then you use `w not in s`; you're checking whether the list a key in `s`. Aside from the fact that lists can't be dictionary keys, this isn't what you want for your algorithm.

Comment: Semantically, what you want is a single "woman", not the entire list of women preferred by a given man (to use the original language of the stable marriage problem).

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this line `if w not in s:`. `w` is a list which breaks your assumption that `dictionary s has keys that are strings (not lists)`.

I am not sure of what you are trying to do here but replacing `if w not in s:` by

```
for women in w:
    if women not in s:
```

could be what you need.